# Should I remove ecommerce tracking after added enhanced ecommerce tracking?

Tags: google-analytics

I was using the ecommerce tracking tag which is

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
  'id': '1234',                     // Transaction ID. Required.
  'affiliation': 'Acme Clothing',   // Affiliation or store name.
  'revenue': '11.99',               // Grand Total.
  'shipping': '5',                  // Shipping.
  'tax': '1.29'                     // Tax.
});
```

Afterwards I implemented the enhanced ecommerce tag:

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {               // Provide product details in an productFieldObject.
  'id': 'P12345',                   // Product ID (string).
  'name': 'Android Warhol T-Shirt', // Product name (string).
  'category': 'Apparel',            // Product category (string).
  'brand': 'Google',                // Product brand (string).
  'variant': 'black',               // Product variant (string).
  'price': '29.20',                 // Product price (currency).
  'coupon': 'APPARELSALE',          // Product coupon (string).
  'quantity': 1                     // Product quantity (number).
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'purchase', {          // Transaction details are provided in an actionFieldObject.
  'id': 'T12345',                         // (Required) Transaction id (string).
  'affiliation': 'Google Store - Online', // Affiliation (string).
  'revenue': '37.39',                     // Revenue (currency).
  'tax': '2.85',                          // Tax (currency).
  'shipping': '5.34',                     // Shipping (currency).
  'coupon': 'SUMMER2013'                  // Transaction coupon (string).
});
```

Should I remove the original one and use enhanced ecommerce only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should remove the old ecommerce tracking code. They should not co-exist. Thanks.